# How to share variables in same playbook.yml at ansible-playbook?

Tags: ansible

playbook.yml

```yaml
- name: dump_db
  hosts: pay_server
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  vars:
    now: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ now }}"
    - copy:
        src: my.cnf
        dest: /tmp/my.cnf
        mode: 0644
    - name: dump
      shell: |
        mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf \
          --set-gtid-purged=OFF \
          --single-transaction db_name  db_tables > /tmp/dump.{{now}}.sql
      args:
        chdir: /tmp
    - name: Download
      fetch:
        src: "/tmp/dump.{{now}}.sql"
        dest: "dump.{{now}}.sql"
        flat: yes
- name: Restore
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - tags: restore
      shell: |
        mysql --defaults-extra-file=local.cnf db_name < dump.{{hostvars['pay_server'].now}}.sql
```

shows error

```yaml
The error was: \"hostvars['pay_server']\" is undefined
```

ansible version:

```
ansible [core 2.12.0]
  config file = /Users/huyinghuan/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/huyinghuan/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/huyinghuan/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/huyinghuan/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Users/huyinghuan/Library/Python/3.8/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:53) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = False
```

---

there is test code:

```
- name: dump_db
  hosts: pay_server
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        now: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ now }}"
- name: Restore
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['pay_server']['now']
```

Result:

[image]

---

Adds on:

I try to use `roles` defined global variable like:

`roles/mysql/vars/main.yml`:

```
now: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
```

test code:

```
- name: dump_db
  hosts: pay_server
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - mysql
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: now
    - shell: |
        # mock task spend time
        sleep 1
- name: Restore
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - mysql
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: now
```

[image]

Comment: Since the question changed heavily, does the documentation about [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) and [Delegating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to share variables ...

One way to do this is to [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) the variable for the host on which the task runs.

```yaml
- name: example
  hosts: host1

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        now: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
    - shell: |
        # tasks will spend some time, example: dump mysql to {{now}}.sql

- name: example2
  hosts: host2

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['host1']['now']
    - shell: |
        # do something, example: restore data to localhost form {{hostvars['host1'].now}}.sql
```

Comment: ERROR: "hostvars['host1']['now']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: If `pay_server` is a host (not group) in your inventory, then that is just the inventory hostname. Actual host is `12.x.x.x` (masked in your screenshot). You can get the variable with `hostvars['12.x.x.x']['now']`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look first into

**Documentation**

- [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [Using Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html)
- [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

and use an inventory and approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    NOW: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Example ONE
    debug:
      msg: "{{ NOW }}"
    when: "'test1' in ansible_hostname"

  - name: Example TWO
    debug:
      msg: "{{ NOW }}"
    when: "'test2' in ansible_hostname"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example ONE] *******
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: '20220726080000'

TASK [Example TWO] *******
ok: [test2.example.com] =>
  msg: '20220726080000'
```

Comment: thanks, your case is  use vars in one playbook's tasks.   my question is if two playbook  in one file run on different hosts(remote server), how to share vars?

Comment: I want run dump mysql command on cloud server [only cloud server has rights access mysql connect ip ],  and download backup.sql to localhost and  restore to 127.0.0.1 mysql database.

Comment: Since within the question just a code snippet without any explanation was dumped, these are new information. You should edit your question and provided it there. Furthermore, with the given approach you could also address your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegate_to` share remote and localhost

test code:

```
- name: dump_db
  hosts: pay_server
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        now: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
    - debug:
        var: now
    - shell: |
        echo {{ now }}
      delegate_to: "localhost"
      delegate_facts: true
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
```